# Error installing python-igraph on Ubuntu (from command line)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, igraph

I'm trying to install python-igraph from command line. I created a new Ubuntu instance on an AWS server, so I have to do everything from command line.  Here is what I have done from a fresh install of Ubuntu:

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install build-essential
$sudo apt-get install python-dev
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install python-pip
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo pip install python-igraph
```

I get the following error:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-XxxMbQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 235, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: http://igraph.wikidot.com/installing-python-igraph-on-linux#toc0
try other options.Install manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install pyhton-igraph on Ubuntu try following steps:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:igraph/ppa
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install python-igraph

p.s There is no package python-igraph available for 12.04 version.

Comment: I've been fighting the igraph install on Ubuntu 12.04 all day using pip. Just tried `apt-get install python-igraph` and it installed no problem.  Not exactly sure why pip is failing. Someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working on Ubuntu 14.04, inside a virtualenv.  It wouldn't be simple to just install the Ubuntu package for python-igraph, since my virtualenv does not include site-packages, IIRC.

Thanks to the helpful and encouraging answer from @Tamás I dug in a bit more when I got the odd `UnicodeDecodeError`.  It seems the real error was

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
```

but it happened after about 13000 lines of build output in which lots of use seemed to have been made of -lxml2 successfully.  Odd.

But based on some advice at

http://igraph.wikidot.com/installing-python-igraph-on-linux#toc0

I installed some libraries:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential libxml2-dev libglpk-dev libgmp3-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libarpack2-dev python-dev
```

I was told:

The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libarpack2-dev libbtf1.2.0{a} libcsparse3.1.2{a} libcxsparse3.1.2{a}    libglpk-dev libgmp-dev{a} libgmp3-dev libgmpxx4ldbl{a} libklu1.2.1{a} libldl2.1.0{a}    libspqr1.3.1{a} libsuitesparse-dev{a} libxml2-dev

After that, the `pip install python-igraph` succeeded.  I kept the whole output in both cases in case someone can use that to fix the packaging issues and help make this more robust.

Bonus tip: Next I couldn't figure out how to get the python cairo bindings, since the igraph documentation didn't talk about a Linux installation of the cairo bindings, and on my own I was getting this error which led me on a frustrating and unsuccessful chase of its own:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pycairo
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pycairo to allow).
```

The solution was to use the more recent set of bindings:

```
pip install cairocffi
```

Comment: oh, thank you so much @Nealmcb I think it was not an easy debug!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be at least partly coming from `pip` - something goes wrong during `pip install python-igraph`, an exception is raised, `pip` catches the exception and tries to save the output into its log file. Unfortunately, a non-ASCII character in the output prevents `pip` from writing into the log file and that's the final exception that you see (not the actual cause of the error). In most of the cases, the non-ASCII characters come from the name of your home directory or your working directory, so first make sure that there aren't any non-ASCII characters in either of them. If that doesn't work, you have to set the default encoding of Python to `utf-8` by creating a file named `sitecustomize.py` somewhere in your Python path and adding this code:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

This will tell Python to encode IO operations with the UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII - hopefully this would enable `pip` to complete the logging phase, and then you can take a look at the actual output. Don't forget to remove `sitecustomize.py` when you are done with debugging.

Comment: Hey @Tamás, what's the difference between using `pip` and `apt-get` to install igraph? Check my comment on the answer above, I was able to get `apt-get` to work but was unsuccessful with `pip`. Let me know and thanks!

Comment: `apt-get install` just downloads and copies a pre-compiled igraph library to the appropriate place on your system. `pip install` downloads the source code and tries to compile it from scratch, although I tried to make it as automatic as possible. If you have some time, please post the output of `pip install python-igraph` somewhere so I can take a look at it and figure out what goes wrong on your machine.

Comment: Thanks @Tamás  See my answer for some extra details.